# Delete record and conditionally delete others LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

Let's say I have the following classes in [LINQ to SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query#LINQ_to_SQL):

```
Module
{
    long MID    // PK
    string Name
}

ModuleBlock
{
    long MID      // FK
    long BID      // FK
}

Block
{
    long BID      // PK
    string Info
}

BlockLanguage
{
    long BID      // FK
    long LID      // FK
}

Language
{
    long LID      // FK
    string Language
}
```

Now, I'd like to delete a set of moduleBlocks

```
var toBeDeletedModuleBlocks = // Query, select ModuleBlocks to be deleted
```

The query for toBeDeletedModuleBlocks is could be arbitrary, as long as it selects ModuleBlocks.

For each Block that has will have 0 of its foreign keys (BID) inside ModuleBlock AFTER ModuleBlocks have been deleted, I'd like to delete that Block.

So basically if there exists a BID in Blocks that does not exist in ModuleBlock, I'd like to delete that Block.

And delete every BlockLanguage with the FK(BID) that is the PK(BID) of the Blocks that are to be deleted.

And this has to happen with ***one*** submitChanges on the datacontext. I've been working on this for an hour, but I simply lack the [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query) knowledge to query everything I need to delete.

In the end I'd like to be able to do this:

```
var toBeDeletedModuleBlocks =
    from moduleBlocks in context.ModuleBlocks
    where block.MID == 5 // assume block with MID = 5 exists
    select moduleBlocks

// Count of each block referenced by ModuleStrings
var allBlocksCount = 
   from moduleBlock in context.ModuleBlocks
   join block in context.Blocks on ModuleBlock.bID equals block.Bid
   group by block by block.BID into counter
   select new
   {
      BID = counter.Key,
      Count = counter.Count()
   };

// Count of each block that is going to be deleted, in this case it has a maximum of 1 (one module in each where).
var theseBlocksCount =
   from moduleBlock in context.ModuleBlocks
   join block in context.Blocks on ModuleBlock.bID equals block.Bid
   where moduleStrings.MID == 5 // 5 again, these are going to be deleted
   groub by 
   select new
   {
      BID = count.Key
      Count = counter.Count()
   }
```

Now I'd like to compare allBlocksCount & theseBlockscount, if Count equals each other that means that there will be 0 references left in BlockString, so I'd like a query that gives me all the Blocks (BIDs) where count in allBlocksCount && theseBlocksCount is equal.

But I don't know enough LINQ to make that query. If I knew how to do that query I could fill **toBeDeletedBlocks** and **toBeDeletedBlockLanguages**

And then I could do this.

```
Context.ModuleBlocks.DeleteAllOnSubmit(toBeDeletedModuleBlocks);
Context.Blocks.DeleteAllOnSubmit(toBeDeletedBlocks);
Context.BlockLanguages.DeleteAllOnSubmit(toBeDeletedBlockLanguages);
Context.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: linq to sql? entity framework? Also, you need to create a better object model. You are writing table-like classes instead of a proper domain model. For example, you have the fk instead of the relationships. Having the relationships will let you do `moduleBlock.Blocks` and use a kind of delete on cascade.

Comment: Can you explain: "for each Block that has will have 0 of it's keys (BID) inside ModuleBlock, I'd like to delete that Block.".

Comment: What is your current query for `toBeDeletedModuleBlocks`.

Comment: I updated my question, hopefully it's more answerable now >_<

Comment: Is this possible in one call to `SubmitChanges`? Will linq-to-sql be able to work out to delete the BlockLanguages from the database before deleting the Blocks?

Comment: You need to start designing your object model instead of copying the database if you want make use of the power of an orm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will work, but this is the logic that you want, right?

```
var remainingBlockIds = context.ModuleBlocks.Except(toBeDeletedModuleBlocks)
                                            .Select(mb => mb.BID)
                                            .Distinct();
var toBeDeletedBlocks = context.Blocks.Where(b => remainingBlockIds.Contains(b.BID) == false);
var toBeDeletedBlockIds = toBeDeletedBlocks.Select(b => b.BID);
var toBeDeletedBlockLanguages = context.BlockLanguages.Where(bl => toBeDeletedBlockIds.Contains(bl.BID));
// Then delete toBeDeletedModuleBlocks, toBeDeletedBlocks, and toBeDeletedBlockLanguages
```

This is alternate logic for deleting BlockLanguages.  It deletes all BlockLanguages that don't have an existing Block, regardless of if the Block was just deleted.  The advantage is it is only dependent on remainingBlockIds.

```
var toBeDeletedBlockLanguages = context.BlockLanguages.Where(bl => remainingBlockIds.Contains(bl.BID) == false);
```

Comment: I think this is it, I'll try it out in a few hours when I'm home

Answer (score 1):

> So basically if there exists a BID in Blocks that  does not exist in
>   ModuleBlock, I'd like to delete that Block.

```cs
var blocksWithoutModules =
    from block in db.Blocks
    where !db.ModuleBlocks.Any(m => m.Block == block)
    select block;
```

> And delete every BlockLanguage with the FK(BID) that is  the PK(BID)
>   of the Blocks that are to be delted

```cs
var languagesToDelete =
    from block in blocksWithoutModules
    select block.Language;
```

> And this has to happen with ONE submitChanges on the datacontex

You can delete the collection of `Block` entities in one go using:

```cs
db.Blocks.DeleteAllOnSubmit(blocksWithoutModules);
db.Languages.DeleteAllOnSubmit(languagesToDelete);

db.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: updated my question again. Your answer assumes that ModuleBlocks have already been deleted, but that is not the case yet.

Comment: sorry but your answer doesn't take **toBeDeletedModuleBlocks** into account. Plus I'm not that good with Linq yet. But I'm sure I'll be able to figure it out eventually.